# How do I complete Challenge 1-18?

Tags: pushmo

I cannot for the life of me figure this level out.

I figure I have to use the white and blue rectangular blocks as stepping stones to the top, but I can't seem to make it work.

How do I complete this challenge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

1. Pull pink block twice
2. stand in font of the blue block and pull it once
3. Jump to the small gap in front of the white block, side pull the blue block twice (you'll have to move back once)
4. Pull the white block once
5. Jump diagonally to the small protruding blue block
6. Push the pink block all the way back
7. Side pull the white block once or twice
8. Pull the pink block once and use the white block to get on top of it